# boostrap modal with form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, input, bootstrap-modal

i've a form. On the button to send data i open a modal, but here there is a problem

```
<div class="container ">
        <form id="partner" method="post">
        <div class="row vdivide">
            <div class="col-sm-5 text-left">
                <label>Dati anagrafici</label>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                        </div>
                        <input class="form-control" name="nome" type="text"
                               placeholder="Inserisci il tuo nome"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                        </div>
                        <input class="form-control" name="congome" type="text"
                               placeholder="Inserisci il tuo cognome" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"/>
                    </div>
                </div>...more input
```

[image]

[image]

when i opne the modal i see in backgroun the input

**EDIT-FOUND PROBLEM**

```
<input class="form-control" name="prova" type="text"
                       placeholder="blabla"/>
```

---->problem is class"-form control", but if i remove it the input becomes like in the photo
[image]

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">INFORMATIVA PRIVACY</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                blabla
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">chiudi</button>
                <button type="button"  id="richiedi" class="btn btn-primary">Procedi con la richiesta</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Anybody know to fix?

Comment: remove `<div class="container ">` will fix the issue

Comment: no, the problem remains

Comment: have you other idea?

Comment: can you post or create fiddle with complete HTML Modal Markup?

Comment: i've found the problem (class of the input tag) but i've no idea to solve it, i edit the question ,see it

Comment: do you have any fiddle, so that we can try to solve it there

Comment: `form control` class has property `width:100%` and removing class is not the solution, if you post the complete Modal HTML or can create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/, will be alot easier to figure out the real problem and solve it

Comment: i added the modal . I create an jsfiddle and it work perfectly. Question: when i launch the modal background becomes black, in fiddle it becomes white. probably import problem?

Comment: Could you share your fiddle?

Comment: the fiddle work, i don't know why. the modal dont'do padding in the input tag

Comment: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/    -> live demo (modal , the form is in the question)